# Is it possible in javax.swing to user two painters in one frame?

Tags: java, swing

I'm recreating the classic snake game. I've already finished coding the snake. What I have to do now is code the walls (that are supposed to be located at the edges of the frame).

As the painter of the snake "repaints" every 30 miliseconds, I thought it would not be really efficient to let this painter draw the walls as well, as the walls stay on the same place during the whole game so it isn't really necessary to redraw the walls every 30 miliseconds.

Thus, I was wondering whether it was possible to have two painters in my game, one that repaints the snake every 30 miliseconds, and one that paints only once (it paints the walls at the beginning of the game)? How should I do that?

These are the most important parts of the code related to the question (full code can be found below this):

```
//this is in the main class
public Snake(){
    painter = new Painter(this);
    this.add(painter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
    timer = new Timer(30, this);
    startGame();
}

    public void startGame(){
    snakeList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    snakeList.addFirst(new Point(10, 10));
    snakeSegments(3);
    setFood(30, 30);
    movementX = 0;
    movementY = 0;
    timer.start(); //timer triggers gameUpdate();
}

public void gameUpdate(){
    snakeMove(movementX, movementY);
    snakeInstructor();
    snakeEat();
    snakeCollision();
    painter.repaint();
}
```

-

```
// this is in the painter class
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    paintSnake(g);
    paintFood(g);
}
```

This is the full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Snake extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
Painter painter;
LinkedList<Point> snakeList;
Timer timer;
Point foodLocation;
int direction;
int snakeSize;
int movementX, movementY;

public static void main(String[] arg){
    new Snake();
}

public Snake(){
    painter = new Painter(this);
    this.add(painter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
    timer = new Timer(30, this);
    startGame();
}

public void startGame(){
    snakeList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    snakeList.addFirst(new Point(10, 10));
    snakeSegments(3);
    setFood(30, 30);
    movementX = 0;
    movementY = 0;
    timer.start();
}

public void gameUpdate(){
    snakeMove(movementX, movementY);
    snakeInstructor();
    snakeEat();
    snakeCollision();
    painter.repaint();
}

public void snakeCollision(){
    for(int i = 4; i < getSnakeSize(); i++){
        if(getFirst().equals(snakeList.get(i))){
            gameOver();
        }
    }
}

public void gameOver(){
    timer.stop();
}

public void snakeEat(){
    if(getFirst().equals(getFood())){
        newFood();
        setSnakeSize();
        snakeSegments(4);
    } 
}

public void snakeSegments(int i){
    snakeSize = i;
    while(snakeSize > 0){
        snakeList.addLast(new Point(getLast()));
        snakeSize--;
    } 
}

public void snakeInstructor(){
    int currentDirection = getDirection();
    if (currentDirection == 1){
        snakeMove(-1, 0);
    } else if (currentDirection == 2){
        snakeMove(1, 0);
    } else if (currentDirection == 3){
        snakeMove(0, -1);
    } else if (currentDirection == 4){
        snakeMove(0, 1);
    }      
}

public void snakeMove(int directionX, int directionY){
    snakeList.getFirst().x = snakeList.getFirst().x + directionX;
    snakeList.getFirst().y = snakeList.getFirst().y + directionY;
    for(int i = getSnakeSize()-1; i >=1; i--) {
        snakeList.get(i).setLocation(snakeList.get(i-1));
    }
}

public void newFood(){
    Random generator = new Random();
    int x = generator.nextInt(49);
    int y = generator.nextInt(47);
    setFood(x, y);
}

public void setFood(int x, int y){
    foodLocation = new Point(x, y);
}

public Point getFood(){
    return foodLocation;
}

public void setDirection(int newDirection){
    direction = newDirection;
}

public int getDirection (){
    return direction;
}

Point getFirst(){
    return snakeList.getFirst();
}

Point getLast(){
    return snakeList.getLast();
}

Point get(int i){
    return snakeList.get(i);
}

public void addFirst(Point p){
    snakeList.addFirst(p);
}

public void addLast(Point p){
    snakeList.addLast(p);
}

public int getSnakeSize(){
    return snakeList.size();
}

public void setSnakeSize(){
    snakeSize = getSnakeSize() + 1;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    gameUpdate();
}

@Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){ }
@Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){ }
@Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && direction != 2){
        setDirection(1);
    } else if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && direction != 1){
        setDirection(2);
    } else if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && direction != 4){
        setDirection(3);
    } else if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && direction != 3){
        setDirection(4);
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        startGame();
    }
}

}
```

-

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Painter extends JPanel{
Snake snake;
public Painter(Snake snake){
    this.snake = snake;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    paintSnake(g);
    paintFood(g);
}

public void paintSnake(Graphics g){
    for(int i = 0; i < snake.getSnakeSize(); i++){
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Point p = snake.snakeList.get(i);
        g.fillRect(p.x*10, p.y*10, 10, 10);
    }
}

public void paintFood(Graphics g){
    Point p = snake.getFood();
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(p.x*10, p.y*10, 10, 10);
}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no...

You could make the `Painter` transparent and overlay the snake on top of the walls, but the call to `g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);` would make that redundant, as it fills the entire component with the current color...

Seen as the `paintComponent` method for both painters would be called every time you want to update the UI, it's also kind of pointless.

A better solution would be to render the map to `BufferedImage` and paint it inside the `painter` before painting the snake.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at buffered images.

Comment: You should use a `BufferedImage` where the content doesn't change or doesn't change often, you could also use multiple `BufferedImage`s in order produce "layers" for different effects, but that's up to you ;)